# many-to-many relation in Qgis usin MSSQL

Tags: qgis, sql-server

Does anyone know how to create many-to-many relation using QGIS and MS SQL?

I have many pipes that are geometry and I need to place in them many cables (not geometry, table with attribute).

Comment: If your cables have an ID that would relate them to the Pipes they fit into, then you can create a many-to-many relationship using a SQL join on the PIPE_ID ... but it sounds like you might be trying to associate each cable with a pipe, meaning you don't have the PIPE_ID in the CABLES table - is that correct?

Comment: No, I have Pipe_ID in Cable table. PIPE table is parent, so in this case I can place many Cables in one Pipe, but I need many cables in many pipes. I try to create new table "CABLE_ROUTE" and to add Pipe_ID and Cable_ID as columns and than I  can create many to many, but I don't now how to show them in Qgis and to add records, avoiding manually importing ID's one by one. I need somehow to create a query or function that will automatically place cables in for example selected features on map.

Comment: Sounds like this is more of a database design question!!!

Comment: It is. I manage to create many to many relat. in db and now I don t know how to show that in Qgis.

Comment: Oh - well... I'm not sure what you're trying to show... your question seems to ask how to assign attributes to your data - but if you have your data in order, what is it you're trying to visualize?

Comment: well i m trying to assign non geometry table (CABLE_ROUTE) to some kind of form that will populate attributes with ID's from selected features. Look at this way: you have a 1000 m cable and you need to placed this cable in 10 pipes also length 1000 m. Pipes are polylines, Cable are only record from a attribute table. I need to select all Pipes on map, and assign id of a cable to all of selected pipes.